# How can I create a rectangle drill in Orcad Layout Plus 10.3?

Tags: layout, footprint, orcad

I use Orcad Layout Plus 10.3 for PCB design and I have a problem at this topic.  For example, I have to use power jack footprint, I have created but the drill can't be rectangle.  I added a screenshot below.  I know I click rectangle but it is disabled.  What can I do?

[image]

Comment: How would you expect your manufacturer to produce a "rectangular drill"?

Comment: @ThePhoton Drilled slot (G85 command in the G-code) for a power jack, but maybe it is not supported by that program- it's a pretty old piece of software.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, A drilled slot is not rectangular. The ends are rounded, with the same radius as half the slot width.

Comment: @ThePhoton True enough. In any case, even that is apparently not supported. Probably the greyed out 'rectangular' is just copied over from the available pad shapes.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear to be possible to directly create oblong slots in Layout Plus. See [this](http://www.edaboard.com/thread200619.html) answer on edaboard:

> Re: create slots in OrCAD
>
> only round type drill holes are allowed in orcad layout plus ( about latest versions i  dont have much ideas). You can provide some special notes in your fabrication layer ( where you include drill table, fabrication notes etc) for the PCB fabricator so that they can cut a plated slot there. I have done it in same boards without issues.

It's directly possible in Altium and other programs such as Allegro.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually i thought this solution but if i do that, drill holes wont be through hole plating. am i right?

Comment: They will be through hole plating if you specify it as such. Routing is usually done after plating. Drilling is always done before, and sometimes after (for unplated holes). The PCB vendor will just do a little edit on your board. G85 is specified to be smooth within 0.13mm and will (as The Photo pointed out) have radiused ends the same as the slot width. If you're using a Chinese vendor make sure you write the instruction in about 5 places and get them to confirm.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it. Maybe i change my pcb designer program. Actually , i have install Altium trial version and i liked it but it is so expensive for me. Thank you for your helping again.

Answer (score 0):

you can place multiple drill holes near by each  to solve this issue